# Pandas - sort and head inside groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have following dataframe:

```
                       uniq_id    value
2016-12-26 11:03:10        001      342
2016-12-26 11:03:13        004        5
2016-12-26 12:03:13        005       14
2016-12-26 12:03:13        008      114
2016-12-27 11:03:10        009      343
2016-12-27 11:03:13        013        5
2016-12-27 12:03:13        016      124
2016-12-27 12:03:13        018      114
```

And i need get top N records for each day sorted by value.
Something like this (for N=2):

```
2016-12-26   001   342
             008   114
2016-12-27   009   343
             016   124
```

Please suggest right way to do that in pandas 0.19.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no yet such method as `DataFrameGroupBy.nlargest()`, which would allow us to do the following:

```
df.groupby(...).nlargest(2, columns=['value'])
```

So here is a bit ugly, but working solution:

```
In [73]: df.set_index(df.index.normalize()).reset_index().sort_values(['index','value'], ascending=[1,0]).groupby('index').head(2)
Out[73]:
       index  uniq_id  value
0 2016-12-26        1    342
3 2016-12-26        8    114
4 2016-12-27        9    343
6 2016-12-27       16    124
```

PS i think there must be a better one...

**UPDATE:** if your DF wouldn't have duplicated index values, the following solution should work as well:

```
In [117]: df
Out[117]:
                     uniq_id  value
2016-12-26 11:03:10        1    342
2016-12-26 11:03:13        4      5
2016-12-26 12:03:13        5     14
2016-12-26 12:33:13        8    114    # <-- i've intentionally changed this index value
2016-12-27 11:03:10        9    343
2016-12-27 11:03:13       13      5
2016-12-27 12:03:13       16    124
2016-12-27 12:33:13       18    114    # <-- i've intentionally changed this index value

In [118]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'value')).reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
Out[118]:
            uniq_id  value
2016-12-26        1    342
2016-12-26        8    114
2016-12-27        9    343
2016-12-27       16    124
```

Comment: it only shows `date` and `value` for me, how to add `uniq_id` field?

Comment: @AlexZaitsev, did you test it against the DF, you've posted in your question?

Comment: @MaxU I'm trying groupby(...).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'value')) but I'm getting weird results like duplicate rows and no filtered data.

Comment: @Boud, that was my first "unsuccessful" attempt to solve this question too ;-)

Comment: @Boud, that's interesting - `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, 'value'))` works just fine if there is no duplicates in the index

Comment: for double index the second solution doesn't work. I can't even understand, in which way it transforms the dataframe, but definitely not the right way

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav, if you mean multi-index saying "double index", then you should know that solutions that work well for normal indices may not be working for multi-index dataframes. If you have such a question please open a new SO question and provide there a reproducible sample data set

Answer (score 3):

A solution that is easier to remember might be:

```py
df.sort_values(by='value').groupby('date').head(2)
```

This will give for each date the two rows with the highest value in `value` column.

In the example from the OT, one would need to set `df['date'] = df.index` before, because the column used for grouping happens to be the index.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.set_index('uniq_id', append=True) \
    .groupby(df.index.date).value.nlargest(2) \
    .rename_axis([None, None, 'uniq_id']).reset_index(-1)


                                uniq_id  value
2016-12-26 2016-12-26 11:03:10        1    342
           2016-12-26 12:03:13        8    114
2016-12-27 2016-12-27 11:03:10        9    343
           2016-12-27 12:03:13       16    124
```

Comment: `'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value'` error

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav, before downvoting please check provided solution __on the dataset, that has been specified in the question__. This solution does answer that particular answer

Comment: okay, now i see, that `.value` is not the pd.DataFrame attribute - it's a column name here